# How do I declare useMutation return type in react query?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I am making an api to post the new recruit announcement and use the response to proceed further actions.

```
interface PostRecruitResponse {
  message: string
}

const postRecruitAPICall = async ({ clubId, data, date }: PostRecruitParams, token: string) => {
  const response = await axios.post<PostRecruitResponse>(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_APIHOST}/club/${clubId}/recruit?semester=${date.semester}&year=${date.year}`,
    data,
    {
      headers: { Authorization: token }
    }
  )
  return response.data.message
}

export const useCreateRecruit = ()  => {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar()
  const token = useAuthHeader()()
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  return useMutation(
    'postRecruit',
    async (values: PostRecruitParams) => {
      const response = await postRecruitAPICall(values, token)
      return response
    }, 
    { onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries('recruits')
    },
    onError: error => {
      if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
        const errorMessage = error.response?.data?.message || COMMON_MESSAGE.ADD_FAIL
        enqueueSnackbar(errorMessage, { variant: 'error' })
      } else {
        enqueueSnackbar(COMMON_MESSAGE.UNKNOWN_ERROR, { variant: 'error' })
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I declared the API like this.

I wanted to use it like

```
const response = createRecruit.mutate({
      clubId,
      data: { ...utcNewRecruitInfo, contents: editorRef.current?.getInstance().getHTML() ?? '' },
      date
    })
if (response === 'ok') ...
```

but it says that 'This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'void' and 'string' have no overlap.'

Comment: Could you post how you are creating `createRecruit` (the full line line, ex, `let createRecruit = ?`. But no matter how you are creating it, I believe will need an `await` to wait for the post to finish, as in to `const response = await createRecruit.mutate({...`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from the mutation function is stored in `mutation.data`, or in your code's case, `createRecruit.data`. There are more examples in ReactQuery's [Mutations documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/mutations).

```js
function onClick() {
  createRecruit.mutate(/* ... */);
}

return (
  <>{createRecruit.isSuccess ? createRecruit.data : "not success yet"}</>;
);
```